# ApiControllers and Razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-web-api

My plan is to have a few dynamically loaded assemblies that may provide some web interfaces.

I decided to put a few WebApi controllers inside those assemblies and some of these controllers can serve html views using inline Razor templates (through custom MediaTypeFormatter). 
It works very well with inline Razor templates so far:

```
var myModel = new {Name:"World"};
var template = "Hello, @Model.Name!";
return Razor.Parse(template, myModel);
```

But the problem I have is I can't figure out how to use/register external Razor views (.cshtml files) located inside my assemblies.

I tried the following so far:

```
var template = Razor.Resolve("MyView.cshtml", myModel);
return template.Run(new ExecuteContext());
```

But my `template` variable is `null`, my guess that MyView.cshtml can't be found, not registered or not referenced correctly.

Comment: Have you set the build action: 'Embedded Resource' in Visual Studio for your cshtml files? Have you configured `Razor.SetTemplateService` with a `TemplateService` which resolves your templates from the correct assemblies?

Comment: @nemesv, no I haven't. Could you push me in the right direction how to implement a `TemplateService` that resolves my templates? Thanks.

Comment: This is how I do it https://github.com/darrelmiller/HypermediaApiSite/blob/master/HypermediaApiContent/Tools/EmbeddedResolver.cs

Comment: Thanks, does anyone of you want to make your comment an answer, so I can accept it? The problem seems to be solved, I just need figure out how to register that resolver for each of my assemblies when they are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

We are using Razor Generator - custom tool for VS (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1f6ec6ff-e89b-4c47-8e79-d2d68df894ec?SRC=VSIDE).

Razor views are being pre-compiled in design time and built-in into assembly as a C# classes. There is no need to include .cshtml files to project as embedded resource.